# Show a child div when link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a series of divs with links and hidden divs. When the link is clicked, I need the hidden div within the parent to be shown. For example:

```
<div class="track" id="track1">
<a href="#" class="notes-link">Song Notes</a>
<div class="song-notes"></div> <!-- HIDDEN DIV TO BE SHOWN WHEN LINK CLICKED -->
</div>

<div class="track" id="track2">
<a href="#" class="notes-link">Song Notes</a>
<div class="song-notes"></div> <!-- HIDDEN DIV TO BE SHOWN WHEN LINK CLICKED -->
</div>
```

So far, the option that I tried opened up ALL of the .song-notes divs, but I want to specify that it's only the child divs of the parent div where the link is contained that should be opened.

Comment: pls include the code you tried

Comment: It's **well worth** your time reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It'll take you about an hour, and save you a *huge* amount of time with simple stuff like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using `.toggle()` here.

```
$('a.notes-link').click(function (){
    $(this).next('.song-notes').toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SB7UL/)**

Comment: This worked great. The other answers were good, but this seemed like the most straightforward solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notes-link').click(function(ev){
       ev.preventDefault();
       $(this).closest('.track').find('.song-notes').show();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WdV4C/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.notes-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/WdV4C/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $('div.track a.notes-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().show(); //$(this).next().toggle();--> to show hide
    });
});
```

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

Add id to the hidden divs

```
<div class="track" id="track1">
<a href="javascript:showNotes(1);" class="notes-link">Song Notes</a>
<div class="song-notes" style="display:none" id="song1">1</div> <!-- HIDDEN DIV TO BE SHOWN WHEN LINK CLICKED -->
</div>

<div class="track" id="track2">
<a href="javascript:showNotes(2);" class="notes-link">Song Notes</a>
<div class="song-notes" style="display:none" id="song2">2</div> <!-- HIDDEN DIV TO BE SHOWN WHEN LINK CLICKED -->
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
    function showNotes(id){
        $('#song'+id).toggle();
    }
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zz65U/